# Can't pause carousel without button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to pause a carousel with the following code:

```
$('#carousel').carousel("pause");
```

However, this doesn't work. When I put it in a function for a button like this:

```
$("#myBtn2").click(function(){
    $("#carousel").carousel("pause");
});
```

It works! Why is this? And how can I get it to work without having to press a button?!

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: you have paused on button click . when you have tried with I am trying to pause a carousel with the following code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#carousel').carousel("pause");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
      $('#carousel').carousel("pause");
});
```